# Arquillian: Problems with Classloader / Classpath during deploying a WAR

Tags: java, maven, integration, jboss-arquillian

I am deploying a test archive via MavenImporter in following way:

```
public static WebArchive createServiceDeployment() { 
  WebArchive serviceArchive = ShrinkWrap .create(MavenImporter.class)  
            .configureFromFile(new File("C:/Users/vbaghdas/.m2/settings.xml")) 
            .loadPomFromFile("../dsuite-parent-demo-service/dsuite-parent-demo-service-impl/pom.xml") 
            .importBuildOutput() 
            .as(WebArchive.class); 
  System.out.println(serviceArchive.toString(true));  
  return serviceArchive;  
}
```

During deploying folowing Exception happens:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.springframework.context.annotation.ScopedProxyMode cannot be cast to org.springframework.context.annotation.ScopedProxyMode
  at org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationScopeMetadataResolver.resolveScopeMetadata(AnnotationScopeMetadataResolver.java:86) ~[spring-context-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner.doScan(ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner.java:250) ~[spring-context-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScanAnnotationParser.parse(ComponentScanAnnotationParser.java:144) ~[spring-context-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:275) ~[spring-context-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:237) ~[spring-context-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:204) ~[spring-context-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:173) ~[spring-context-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:321) ~[spring-context-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:243) ~[spring-context-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:273) ~[spring-context-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:98) ~[spring-context-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:681) ~[spring-context-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:523) ~[spring-context-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) ~[spring-boot-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar:1.4.0.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:759) ~[spring-boot-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar:1.4.0.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:369) ~[spring-boot-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar:1.4.0.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:313) ~[spring-boot-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar:1.4.0.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.run(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:150) ~[spring-boot-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar:1.4.0.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.createRootApplicationContext(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:130) ~[spring-boot-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar:1.4.0.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.onStartup(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:86) ~[spring-boot-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar:1.4.0.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:169) ~[spring-web-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5167) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
  at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:152) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]

  ... 10 more
```

I checked my classpath - I I have only 1 version of problematic spring-context jar, and I have it indeed only once in the classpath - so I uderstand the problem even fewer now

Comment: _I have only 1 version of problematic spring-context jar, and I have it indeed only once in the classpath_ what you mean is that spring-context.jar only appear in your application server's classpath only? But from the exception it seems that your war also included spring-context.jar file?

Answer (score 0):

Try to run maven dependency:tree to get jars dependent on this project to make sure only one spring jar getting loaded without duplicate transitive dependency jars